# GCM Reg ID is empty

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Hi I am trying to implement GCM push notification. I am getting an empty GCM id.
Here is my code:

```
public void registerClient() {

        try {
        // Check that the device supports GCM (should be in a try / catch)
        GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
        GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
        regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);


        if (regId.equals("")) {
            registrationStatus = "Registering...";
            GCMRegistrar.register(this, PROJECT_ID);
            regId="sfsaas";
            regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
            registrationStatus = "Registration Acquired";
            Log.i("******IN_IF_REGID*****", regId);
            Log.i("INSIDE","if");
        } 
        else 
        {
            Log.i("INSIDE","else");
            registrationStatus = "Already registered";
            Log.i("******REGID*****", regId);
        }

        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            registrationStatus = e.getMessage();
        }

}
```

Here is my Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.eventnotifier"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<permission
    android:name="com.example.eventnotifier.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"     />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.eventnotifier.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 

<!-- Camera permission -->
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<!-- receives GCM messages -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<!-- GCM connects to Google services -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<!-- GCM requires a Google account -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_OWNER_DATA" />

<!-- wake the processor if a GCM message is received -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:color/black" >

    <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"     android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.example.eventnotifier" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.eventnotifier.HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.eventnotifier.RegisterActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
        </activity>

     <activity
        android:name="com.example.eventnotifier.DateActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
     </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.eventnotifier.DescriptionActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
     </activity>

     <activity
        android:name="com.example.eventnotifier.MyEventActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
     </activity>

     <activity
        android:name="com.example.eventnotifier.CreateEventActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
     </activity>

     <activity
        android:name="com.example.eventnotifier.LocationActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
     </activity>

     <activity
        android:name="com.example.eventnotifier.AddGuestActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
     </activity>

     <activity
        android:name="com.example.eventnotifier.ContactListActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
     </activity>

     <activity
        android:name="com.example.eventnotifier.ContactTest"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
     </activity>

     <activity
        android:name="com.example.eventnotifier.InvitedGuestsActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
     </activity>

     <activity
        android:name="com.example.eventnotifier.MyInvitationsActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
     </activity>

     <activity
        android:name="com.example.eventnotifier.UnregisteredGuestsActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
     </activity>

     <activity
        android:name="com.example.eventnotifier.RecentGuestsActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

     </activity>
 </application>  
</manifest>
```

This line is not getting printed -Log.i("******IN_IF_REGID*****", regId); Can you guys help me out?
I have to submit this project tomorrow. Any help will be appreciated! 
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work like that.

`GCMRegistrar.register` initiates a request to GCM server, asking it for a Registration ID. This is an asynch request. `GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId` returns a cached value of the Registration ID, so if your device is not registered, it returns null.

The Registration ID is returned in the `GCMIntentService.onRegistered` method.

Here's the code of [GCMIntentService](http://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/browse/samples/gcm-demo-client/src/com/google/android/gcm/demo/app/GCMIntentService.java?r=b2b02f2050692449d7217f4ce7e146e4cd344490) from the GCM Demo.

This is the code of `GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId` :

```
/**
 * Gets the current registration id for application on GCM service.
 * <p>
 * If result is empty, the registration has failed.
 *
 * @return registration id, or empty string if the registration is not
 *         complete.
 */
public static String getRegistrationId(Context context) {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences(context);
    String registrationId = prefs.getString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, "");
    // check if app was updated; if so, it must clear registration id to
    // avoid a race condition if GCM sends a message
    int oldVersion = prefs.getInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
    int newVersion = getAppVersion(context);
    if (oldVersion != Integer.MIN_VALUE && oldVersion != newVersion) {
        Log.v(TAG, "App version changed from " + oldVersion + " to " +
                newVersion + "; resetting registration id");
        clearRegistrationId(context);
        registrationId = "";
    }
    return registrationId;
}
```

As you can see, it returns a locally stored value of the Registration ID. In order for it to return anything, `GCMRegistrar.setRegistrationId(Context context, String regId)` must be called, with the Registration ID that was returned to `GCMIntentService`.
And it's called in `GCMBaseIntentService` :

```
    private void handleRegistration(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        GCMRegistrar.cancelAppPendingIntent();
        String registrationId = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_REGISTRATION_ID);
        String error = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_ERROR);
        String unregistered = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_UNREGISTERED);
        Log.d(TAG, "handleRegistration: registrationId = " + registrationId +
                ", error = " + error + ", unregistered = " + unregistered);

        // registration succeeded
        if (registrationId != null) {
            GCMRegistrar.resetBackoff(context);
            GCMRegistrar.setRegistrationId(context, registrationId);
            onRegistered(context, registrationId);
            return;
        }
    ...
    }
```

Comment: So should i collect the regId in the GCMIntentService.onRegistered method?

Comment: If you call `GCMRegistrar.register`, than you should collect the regID from the `onRegistered` method and pass it to your server. If the device is already registered, you don't have to call register, and in that case you can get the regID from GCMRegistrar (though in that case your server should already have the registration ID, so I don't see why you'll need to get it). You can call `GCMRegistrar.isRegistered` in order to know if you are already registered, and based on that decide whether to call `register`.

Comment: Is there anyway i can get the regID in my MainActivity also along with the service? Because I am inserting my data in my datadabase from the Mainactivity

Comment: Hey Eran thanks for the help. Was able to successfully send the regid to the server!! :)

Answer (score 0):

The first time is going to be null, if the registration is correct then the next time regid is not going to be null.

Remember to add at your GCMIntentService your SENDER_ID on the constructor

```
public GCMIntentService(){
    super(SENDER_ID);
}
```

Well you have defined it as PROJECT_ID, check if it is the number next to the url

> https: //code.google.com/apis/console/#project:{SENDER_ID}

on your Google Api Project

Comment: I am getting the regID in my GCMIntentService onRegistered(). Is there a way that i can send data to my Activity?