# Get GCM Registration id using asynctask

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I used this script to get registration id in `doInbackground` AsyncTask but registration id still empty. No error or forced closed but registration id empty.

```
public class RegisterTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {

public RegisterTask(RegisterActivity activity, ProgressDialog progressDialog) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.progressDialog = progressDialog;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    progressDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected Integer doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    inputFullName = (EditText) activity.findViewById(R.id.registerName);
    inputEmail = (EditText) activity.findViewById(R.id.registerEmail);
    inputPassword = (EditText) activity.findViewById(R.id.registerPassword);
    String name = inputFullName.getText().toString();
    String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
    String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
    Log.v(email, password);
    UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();

    // Make sure the device has the proper dependencies.
    GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(activity);

    // Make sure the manifest was properly set - comment out this line
    // while developing the app, then uncomment it when it's ready.
    GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(activity);

    // lblMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblMessage);

    activity.registerReceiver(activity.mHandleMessageReceiver,
            new IntentFilter(DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION));
    // Get GCM registration id
    regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(activity);

    JSONObject json = userFunction.registerUser(name, email, password,
            regId);
    // check for login response
    try {
        if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
            // registerErrorMsg.setText("");
            String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
            if (Integer.parseInt(res) == 1) {
                // user successfully registred
                // Store user details in SQLite Database
                DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(
                        activity.getApplicationContext());
                JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                // Clear all previous data in database
                userFunction.logoutUser(activity.getApplicationContext());
                db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_ID_USER),
                        json_user.getString(KEY_NAMA),
                        json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL),
                        json_user.getString(KEY_REGID),
                        json_user.getString(KEY_JKEL),
                        json_user.getString(KEY_TLAHIR),
                        json_user.getString(KEY_INSTANSI),
                        json_user.getString(KEY_JABATAN),
                        json_user.getString(KEY_DIBUAT_AT),
                        json_user.getString(kEY_AVATAR),
                        json_user.getString(kEY_STATUS));
                // successful registration
                responseCode = 1;
            } else {
                // Error in registration
                responseCode = 0;
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return responseCode;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Integer responseCode) {
    EditText userName = (EditText) activity
            .findViewById(R.id.registerEmail);
    EditText passwordEdit = (EditText) activity
            .findViewById(R.id.registerPassword);
    String s = userName.getText().toString();

    if (responseCode == 1) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        activity.registerReport(responseCode);
        userName.setText("");
        passwordEdit.setText("");
    }
    if (responseCode == 0) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        activity.registerReport(responseCode);
    }
}
}
```

please help

Comment: This is not the way it works, it will be always empty if you don't login first ar GCM services using `GCMRegistrar.register(Context)`.
[Read the Google Cloud M. documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html)

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16345292/gcm-reg-id-is-empty).

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a request to obtain the id using GCMRegistrar.register(mContext). You will have to declare a receiver in manifest file to enable receiving registration and message intent. And now to actually receive the message you will have to implement your own service that will extend GCMBaseIntentService. [Here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/) you can find a tutorial of GCM.

Comment: can me put GCMRegistrar.register(mContext) in doinbackground? final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(activity);
  if (regId.equals("")) {
   // Registration is not present, register now with GCM   
   //GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
   GCMRegistrar.register(activity, SENDER_ID);
  }